# if/else value in cgridview - yii

Tags: yii

Is it possible to do this?

so i have two parties, A and B. If it is user A then he can click on Accept link, if not, then do something else (disable the link). 
What doesn't work `'visible'` because this hides the entire column. Party A may have both scenario where it needs to click/not click.

looking for something like this :

```
'value'=>'CHtml::Link("Accept", array("$data->partyA()?array("site/accept):""", "id"=>$data->id));',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use anonymous function as value:

```
'value'=>function($data,$row){
   if ($data->partyA()) return CHtml::link();
   else return "";
}
```

Use `'type'=>'raw'` for this column. Also if you want to pass external parameters to grid add:

```
'value'=>function($data,$row) use($external){}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    'value'=>'CHtml::link("Accept", # check your condition here # ? array("site/accept"):"#",
 array("id"=>$data->id);'
```